# App Store does not show my updated version after approval

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have added some feature and enhancements to my app and uploaded the updated binary on Sep 21st, Apple approved with status “**Pending Developer Release**” on `Sep 23 11.45pm(IST)`. In the next 5 minutes I just released the app(v1.0.2) on clicking “**Release This Version**” and app status changed to “**Ready For Sale**”. Today it is Sep 26th still my older(1.0.1) version not updated with latest version(1.0.2) in the app store. 
In some article I read it will take up to 24hrs but in my case its been 3days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked "Automatically release this version"  on submit?

Comment: No. I have selected Manually Release the version

Comment: IF you selected "Manually Release the version" means. Apple wont publish it automatically. You need to manually release your new version

Comment: Did your prob got solved?

Comment: Yes i got solution, thank you

Comment: Then accept the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got appeared latest version of my app in the app store.

I just edited my app description and re-saved my changes, after few minutes updated version appeared in the app store. it may be a caching issue, but its work for me.

Thank you for your time. Hope this helps (-_-)

Comment: I am new to iOS, I released first version and it got upload after following couple of steps. Now I have created new version of it, since UI is updated, I have also uploaded new screenshots. I uploaded new version and it was ready to sale in Know time after I published it. 

The status of updated version is "Ready for sale" and it is green, but still I  can see screenshots of old version. What is that? Why I am looking old screenshots ?

Comment: I have updated Promotional Text and it start showing up in an app store within an hour. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to wait. When you press "Release This Version", new version of your app appears in App Store with a delay.

If you checking on a device - try to restart it to avoid displaying cached app page in App Store.

If you keep seeing old app version after restart even waiting too long - contact Apple support.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "version release" as "Manual", then after the app is approved it is published only when you release it yourself.

Comment: Please read the question, the app was not "Pending Developer Release", it was "Ready For Sale".